# How to embed/integrate functionality for text formatting at run time in android app?

Tags: android, spannablestring, text-formatting, android-developer-api, spannable

I am creating an Android application for Pets, people can place an ad to sell their pet, so, the user can type the description of the ad. But I want to embed/integrate text format system for the description(for example the user can bold, italic & underline the text, add links, etc) content same as the WordPress application does for example:

[image]

What I did is I decided to use the `SpannableString` API but during the time when I moved forward in the development I feel this is not the solution, and in fact, it is not the solution to my problem.

I am storing data in the server so, I want to achieve such solution so that the retrieval of data should be exactly formatted as the user did. Is there any library or API for this function or how can we implement such functionality in the android app? Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so there is any library or API to solve your problem.

Comment: @Daddy Boy - How the WordPress app is working for this functionality? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I believe they are using webview, and they integrated their own default text formatting module that they already use for WordPress site area.

Comment: Do you have any idea in your mind? How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You have to create your own text formatting scheme, this is what I can suggest!!!

Comment: Anyways thanks for your suggestions I am glad!!!